# Here map offline route not working until app restart

Tags: android, here-api

I'm trying to perform offline navigation using Here Maps Android SDK, Navigate Edition.
After successfully download map data I try to calculate a route (with `OfflineRoutingEngine`) but I have the following error:

> E/routing-offline: [ERROR] routing-offline - Failed to calculate the
> route description, error code: 11, routing error: 1

Everything works **if I restart the app**, but there's no way to get a route right after downloading map data.
Before the route request, I check if everything is in place with  `mapDownloader.getInstalledRegions()`. I get the right Region installed and I see the following line in logcat so I guess everything is in order.

> I/CacheUpdateManager: [INFO ] CacheUpdateManager -
> GetInstalledMapRegions: catalog_handle=0,
> regions=[{region_id=20127658, status=Installed}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem / bug. Just don't reuse the same `RoutingEngine` after downloading map data.

Comment: This should only be an issue if you have initialized the RoutingEngine with a different SDKNativeEngine.